# Do you have DRM problems in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, drm

I have not used Vista, but heard that it contained DRM measures that can make legitimate computer use more difficult. For example, from [this article](http://www.forbes.com/2007/02/10/microsoft-vista-drm-tech-security-cz_bs_0212vista.html):

> Certain high-quality output
>   paths--audio and video--are reserved
>   for protected peripheral devices.
>   Sometimes output quality is
>   artificially degraded; sometimes
>   output is prevented entirely. And
>   Vista continuously spends CPU time
>   monitoring itself, trying to figure
>   out if you're doing something that it
>   thinks you shouldn't. If it does, it
>   limits functionality and in extreme
>   cases restarts just the video
>   subsystem.

Others said [this was bunk](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Ou/?p=429), but some [specific issues](http://www.electronista.com/articles/08/01/04/vista.drm.and.netflix/) have been reported.

**So: what about Windows 7? Is there anything you can't do with it specifically because of the DRM that's built-in?**

Comment: You'll find some interesting information about and advocacy against DRM in Vista, and now Windows 7, at http://badvista.fsf.org ... I'm on the fence: I do like and use Vista and Windows 7, but I wish it didn't have technologies built-in that treat me like a thief!

Comment: I won't lie, I've erred on the wrong side of legal in Vista, but any supposed DRM in it has never appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope!

Any DRM that there is in 7 has not affected me in one bit yet.

So many people said this about Vista, however I did not notice any problems. There was a huge bug in Vista with file copy speeds that people said was the DRM, however it was later fixed.

Using command prompt and doing copy was not affected so I don't think we will ever know if it was DRM or just bug.

Anyway, I was a happy Vista user and now I am a happy 7 user.

I know that there is DRM regarding HD disks and HDCP, however I do not use HD discs and unlike game/software DRM, I do not think that this is obtrusive - and it is as DRM should be, it just works without bugging the user.